# how to use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I currently have hibernate.ddl set:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

I don't to lose my data again and again...
What value I can use Instead of deleting and creating the schema every time 
Is there a way to update the existing one?
I was trying to use **update** in place of **create-drop** but it throws an exception:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project fno-connector-core: 
An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: 
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/..../classes/data.sql]: 
insert into users (username, enabled, password, first_name, last_name, email) 
values ('admin', true, '************', 'Flexera', 'Admin', 'aurovindosahu@*****.com'); 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible values of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` are  `e.g. none | validate | update | create | create-drop`.  [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Make use of `update` in your usecase.

Comment: First i am using create and after that If i use update then it throws exception

Comment: What is the exception? You can first drop the tables then re-run a fresh program with `update`.